# select unique combinations of some columns in R, and random value for another column

Tags: r, plyr

Suppose I have a data frame, myD, with the following columns: x, y, a, b.

I want to select unique combinations of x and y. That part is easy, just use unique on the first two columns. However, for each unique combination of x,y there are multiple values of a and b; I want to select a random row. I.e., among all of the rows that match a particular combination of x,y, I simply want to randomly select just one of the rows. Note that I don't want to independently sample a and b; they should come from the same row.

I was using ddply to do this:

```
ddply(myD, c("x","y"), summarize,
        a=a[1],
        b=b[1])
```

This of course gets the first pair of a,b for each combination of x,y; I was randomly permuting the entire data frame to achieve uniformity.

Anyway, this ddply command is extremely slow when the data frame has a million rows or more. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried it as `ddply(myD, .(x, y), ...)`? What are the column classes of the data frame?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a fast and simple solution.

First, randomly permute the rows:

```
myD <- myD[sample(1:dim(myD)[1],replace=FALSE),]
```

Next, keep only the first row for each unique combination of x and y:

```
myD <- myD[!duplicated(myD[,c("x","y")]),]
```

Answer (score 0):

Since speed is important here I would suggest a combination of the `data.table` package and the `sample` function.  `data.table` can do many of the same things `plyr` can do but much much faster.  Something like this might work...

```
#Make fake data
set.seed(3)
myD <- data.frame(x=c("s","s","s","t","t","t"),y=c("u","u","v","v","w","w"),
    a=rnorm(6),b=rnorm(6))

#See data
myD
# x y           a           b
# 1 s u -0.96193342  0.08541773
# 2 s u -0.29252572  1.11661021
# 3 s v  0.25878822 -1.21885742
# 4 t v -1.15213189  1.26736872
# 5 t w  0.19578283 -0.74478160
# 6 t w  0.03012394 -1.13121857

require("data.table")

myD <- data.table(myD)
myD[,rand.row:=sample(1:.N,1),by=c("x","y")]
myD <- myD[,list(a=a[rand.row],b=b[rand.row]),by=c("x","y","rand.row")]
myD

#   x y  rand.row       a           b
# 1: s u        1 -0.96193342  0.08541773
# 2: s v        1  0.25878822 -1.21885742
# 3: t v        1 -1.15213189  1.26736872
# 4: t w        2  0.03012394 -1.13121857
```

Answer (score 0):

I have not built data to test this on, but I have found `dplyr` to be faster than `plyr`, so this command:

```
library(dplyr)

df_sampled <- myD %.%
group_by(x, y) %.% 
summarize(a = a[1], b = b[1])
```

Ought to give you better performance.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, dplyr requires R 3.0, and given the amount of code, I would prefer to not risk breaking anything by moving to a newer version.